# add multiple column to radiobuttonlist textfield

Tags: c#, textfield, multiple-columns, radiobuttonlist

I'm developing a website by using C# 4.0. I need to add `RadioButtonList` `TextField` multiple column from database. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code snippet.

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="MultiFieldRBList1" runat="server" ></asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Fetch data from database.
        var list = Game.GetAll();
        var query = from c in list
                 select new Data
                 {
                     Column1 = c.Id,
                     MultipleCplumn = c.Title + "(" + c.Year + ")"
                 };
        MultiFieldRBList1.DataSource = query;
        MultiFieldRBList1.DataTextField = "MultipleCplumn";
        MultiFieldRBList1.DataValueField = "Column1";
        MultiFieldRBList1.DataBind();

    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    public string MultipleCplumn { get; set; }
}
```

**Another way**
If you want to reuse this control at several places then best way is to create a custom radiobuttonlist control for this.
Check [this](http://www.governor.co.uk/blog/2009/1/27/binding-multiple-fields-to-radiobuttonlist-item-text) link

Comment: thx @geek , but these columns is not aligned , i wrote it manually by hand thx again...